# подключение библиотеки

Tags: android

просьба помочь подключить эту библиотеку
[android-TNRAnimationHelper](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/4572#!package)

при стандартном подключении получаю такую ошибку

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Второй пункт из инструкции выполнили?

Comment: Я первый не знаю, как выполнить. Использую Андроид Студио.

Comment: Содержимое build.gradle покажите. Только не скриншотом

Comment: @temq добавил содержимое

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Разобрался: библиотека требовала минимальный 16-й SDK, а у меня 15-й стоял.